# ¿Cómo puedo programar notificaciones locales con Kotlin desde variables?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

buenas tardes.
Feliz domingo a todos.

Me estoy iniciando en la programación de apps para Android con kotlin y me gustaría poder programar notificaciones locales pero en vez de usar un DatePickerDialog y TimePickerDialog quisiera programarlas desde dos variables en las que tengo guardadas la fecha y la hora, estas variables están en String.

Encontré este tutorial pero lo hacen desde los pickers para la fecha y el horario
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D0VpASTpgmw&lc=UgzG_LB8u1BHaXSXs0p4AaABAg
Código: https://github.com/sriharsha1507/set_repetitive_exact_alarm

¿Conocen algún tutorial o material en el que expliquen como se pueden programar las notificaciones desde variables y no desde los pickers?

Ojalá puedan ayudarme.
Saludos

Comment: Hay un [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/advanced-android-kotlin-training-notifications) sobre notificaciones. Pero ten en cuenta que las preguntas que buscan recursos externos no son bienvenidas en este sitio. Lee [ask]